# Responsive Select Menu - Javascript only with onChange

Tags: javascript, mobile, menu

I encountered a strange issue today. My responsive menu does not seem to be working on all mobile devices. On the Samsung S5 when I click on any option, the page loads, but the menu does not disappear/close. When I select something else, it does not redirect again.

I am trying to use a simple onchange script. Any help is appreciated.

```
<select id="mobile-menu" onChange="if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value;">
<option selected disabled>Navigation Menu</option>
<option value="link1.shtml">Home</option>
<option value="link2.shtml">Services</option>
<option value="link3.shtml">Testimonials</option>
<option value="link4.shtml">Faq</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onChange` attribute can cancel further *normal* input operations (like closing the select), if the JavaScript inside returns a "falsy" value. Try adding a `return true;` at the end of your `onChange`.

```
<select id="mobile-menu" onChange="if (this.value) window.location.href = this.value; return true;">
  <option selected disabled>Navigation Menu</option>
  <option value="link1.shtml">Home</option>
  <option value="link2.shtml">Services</option>
  <option value="link3.shtml">Testimonials</option>
  <option value="link4.shtml">Faq</option>
</select>
```